# Decrypt field in SRSS Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I need some assistance with creating a decryption custom code to decrypt a column value in SSRS.

In DB it is storing in Encryption format, I am doing the encryption in C# code, and storing in DB.
Now i want to show the same column value in report in its decrypted state.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a shared function in VB.NET and use it in an expression or add a custom assembly with C# code. Both methods are [well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15).